# Is it possible to prove that a forwarded email has been tampered with prior to being forwarded?

Tags: email

I have requested that an old email exchange between myself and HR be forwarded to me by a previous employer. They complied with the request but I suspect that the body of the exchange which they forward to me was edited prior to being forwarded.

My previous employer sent me the email exchange by copy/pasting it into the body of a new email.

Is there anyway to confirm that the body of the original exchange was tampered with?

Comment: Just to be clear, you can't even tell if an email sent directly to you wasn't tampered with after being sent if you don't use signing/encryption.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you cannot detect if a mail was tampered with. You can only detect this if the mail was signed and the person you suspect to tamper with the mail is not in possession of the key needed to sign the mail again. In theory it might be possible to store a fingerprint or similar for all delivered mails and thus check if this is the original mail, but I doubt that there is something like this in your at this employer, because it is not common.

Comment: Is there a way knowing from the header if the forwarded email was edited via some sort of "total editing time" attribute, like the ones word processors have?

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati: no. There is nothing like this.